# Symfony2 application very slow in VirtualBox

Tags: performance, symfony, virtualbox, php

I run a virtual copy of Debian on VirtualBox to develop a larger-sized PHP application on a nginx/php5-fpm/MySQL stack. Development happens in the host OS (Windows 7 x64), the code is mounted as a shared folder in the guest OS.

Performance is very bad. The following are webgrind outputs for the native vbox filesystem and a samba mount with cifs:

[image: vboxfs profiling]
[image: smbfs profiling]

In either case `filemtime`, `file_exists` and `is_readable` take several seconds to run. CPU load is very high, memory usage seems normal.

Isn't the output of all three of these functions cached in the stat cache? Why are they taking so long?

I'd really appreciate any help I can get!

**Edit:** To clarify, production performance is fine. On our (proper, non-virtual) staging server the PHP code executes in ~60ms max in production settings and somewhere between 100-200ms in dev mode.

I need help figuring out why VirtualBox is 100x slower in dev & prod mode.

I just checked, production settings yield ~5sec execution. Still unusable, plus it's awkward to develop with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use nfs file sharing. Samba and the vbox file share can be very slow.

Your profiling indicates that file system operations are the bottleneck.

Read this blog post http://clock.co.uk/tech-blogs/virtualbox-404-shared-folder-update for more insight

Answer (score 5):

I recently answered a similar question. You can find my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8283894/697930).

I will make a small resume of it. You should not measure performance of your application based solely on the `app_dev.php` front controller. This controller has been created to be used for development only. In development, you make lots of changes to configuration files, twig templates, assets, etc. Symfony will check hundred of files for modifications and reload a lot of previously cached stuff if necessary hence the high number of calls to `filemtime`, `file_exists` and `is_readable`. All this calls are bypassed in production mode because Symfony expect everything in the cache to be up-to-date. So, almost everything possible is cached in production mode and used right ahead without Symfony checking if the file has been modified or not. This gives a huge performance boost because reloading a single files in development can take a lot of times to parse it, check dependencies on it, recache everything depending on this files and so on.

If you'are benchmarking your application, benchmark it as if it was in production mode. At least, if you can't have all the hardware setup as you expect it in production, do the following steps. Clear your cache for production mode and use `app.php` instead of `app_dev.php`. Also, check the section on [performance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/performance.html) that can be found on symfony.com in the documentation. Here the console calls to clear and warmup your cache in production environment. I think `cache:clear` will also warmup the cache, but since I'm not 100% sure, I prefer to make both calls:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Thank you, Matt! You were right about the difference between prod and dev mode, the three PHP functions I mentioned disappeared completely from the profiler.

However I'm still wondering why VirtualBox takes so long to execute my code. I've clarified that in my question above.

Cheers, Philipp

Comment: I can't tell for sure why VirtualBox is so slow. Maybe this VM isn't particularly good with filesystem interaction. You could try other VMs to check how well they perform. Maybe what @PeteMitchell answered could help. At this point, I would focus my searching effort on VirtualBox. Good luck with your problem. Regards, Matt

Answer (score 4):

Just to tie this up:

In the end I set up a samba share on the guest OS, bound it to a second network adapter ([host-only, like in this guide](http://www.wiredrevolution.com/virtualbox/setup-ssh-access-between-virtualbox-host-and-guest-vms)) and mounted that as a network drive in the host OS.

A little hacky, but execution times are down to 100-500ms from 5-13sec in dev mode with profiling.

Comment: Thinking about the same, as I've exactly the same performance issue. Tried vboxsf mount, NFS... its few times slower than just direct file read/write. Unfortunately I do plenty of searches on the repository through my Eclipse, while searching something... and it seems to be ways slower.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what `Matt` said I recommend you to compile twig extension and use it as php module. It will generate templates faster. But still the most important is to do any benchmarks running your app in prod environment, but not in dev or test. Make sure you don't load xdebug module in production, because it will slow down your benchmarks as well.

I don't know your exact settings, but most-likely you will have better results if you install proper reverse proxy (aka Varnish) instead of `AppCache` to make as little requests to app itself as possible.

Comment: I'll check out the C extension, thanks Anton. I've got no complaints about performance in production settings on a similar, but physical Debian installation. I've expanded my question above, sorry if it was ambiguous.

Comment: Just found that one of my colleagues is using VirtualBox and he had similar problems before he allocated more memory for it. Try it, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, fixed it by setting up a rsync cron that keeps the code on the VM and the host in sync.

Apparently Virtualbox shared folders are pretty slow when it comes to file reading/writing :/

[Blogged about my solution in detail if you are interested](http://www.davidbehler.de/2015/12/how-to-improve-symfony2-performance-when-running-from-shared-folder-on-vm/)