# Symfony's initialize time is very slow

Tags: performance, symfony, virtualbox

I'm calling dev/my_app/web/app_dev.php/ and wait 2,4 sec for the welcome site to load 1,8 sec of which is initializing and RoutingService. That's pretty slow.
I'm looking at some videos and thay have 65 ms overall response time. That's what I'm aiming at :)

I have:

- disabled xdebug (it's gone)
- enabled APC
- optimized autoloader (composer dump-autoload --optimize)
- checked if I'm using only IP addresses

Got fresh Symfony and just installed FOSBundle.

[image: that's what my profiler says]

Running:

- Symfony 2.3.1
- on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS on VirtualBox
- PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6

Comment: Since it's a VM, I hope you've checked running processes of the host OS to be sure it's not trashing or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 application very slow in VirtualBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882411/symfony2-application-very-slow-in-virtualbox)

Comment: @forgottenbas: thanks, that opened my eyes on VirtualBox's performance. I've installed Symfony2 on my host windows machine and out of the box I get "Initalization time" - 147ms and "Total time" 380ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be a Virtualbox thing as @forgottenbox mention in the direct comments box under the question.

I've installed Symfony2 on my host Windows7/WAMP and out of the box I get "Initalization time" - 147ms and "Total time" 380ms for a "Hello World" demo app so I see a big difference.

Comment: I switched to VMware - I get 44ms for a Welcome controller in Symfony2, that is much better - like 56x faster :D. Imagine my hapiness now ;)

Answer (score -1):

You're checking dev environment. Check timing on production and see how much it is.
For speeding up routing itselft you can also try to enable apache router

Comment: But even on dev environment this is too much, and no matter how "dev" it might be, it's Ubuntu with stable PHP (even if on a VM), so I also wouldn't expect it to be that bad.

Comment: Thanks, your tips got me to 1.5-3s on dev and 1-2s on production. Still something. But so irregular, I don't understand why.. :) I had a problem with writing to cache, but it's solved now. Still it's way longer than even ~100ms.